# Title not showing on UIButton Gradient View

Tags: ios, swift

I have a gradient class attached to my UIButton and the gradient shows fine. However, the title or text of the UIButton is not showing. It seems the gradient is covering the text. Heres my code:

```
@IBDesignable
class GradientView: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var topColor: UIColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.0318463631, blue: 0, alpha: 1) {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var bottomColor: UIColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.4265971184, blue: 0, alpha: 1) {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [topColor.cgColor, bottomColor.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
        gradientLayer.cornerRadius = layer.cornerRadius
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
            //Rounded Button Functions
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius : CGFloat = 3.0 {
        didSet {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.setupView()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        self.setupView()
    }


    func setupView() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    }

    @IBInspectable var border : CGFloat = 1.0 {
        didSet {
            self.layer.borderWidth = border
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            return UIColor(cgColor: layer.borderColor!)
        }
        set {
            layer.borderColor = newValue?.cgColor
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know what the problem is. I used this code for another project and it showed fine. 
Thanks

Comment: try to add super.layoutSubviews() in layoutSubviews method. I think it is a problem.

Comment: While I tried to replicate the issue, I have tried Andrew Romanov's suggestion. It is working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to call `super.layoutSubviews()` in the `layoutSubviews()`.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    // your code
}
```